# Power series representation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

The function to represent as a power series is: $$ \frac {10} {(x-10)^2} $$

Any help is, as always, appreciated.

Comment: It's impressive that you were so quickly able to see the anti-derivative of the expression! In truth, the question was 'If the function is $$ \frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{10}} $$, what is the series representation of $$ f'(x) $$

Comment: ? Are you talking to yourself?

Comment: @GFauxPas hahah, no someone had left a comment just a couple minutes ago, I guess they deleted it.

Comment: I made a comment but in haste deleted it, wasn't able to repost. Luckily they saw it and it was of help.

Comment: @kmeis I did see the comment and left one of my own in response, I hope you can get back to me based on what it says.

Comment: As you stated, the question is (or at least can be) solved by finding the derivative of a known power series. We can note that : $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{10}} = \frac{1}{10\left (1-\frac{x}{10} \right )^2 } = \frac{10}{(x-10)^2}$. Known too is :$\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{10}} = \sum \left ( \frac{x}{10} \right ) ^n$. Differentiating this series will then result in what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a useful **finite** evaluation:
$$
1+u+u^2+...+u^n=\frac{1-u^{n+1}}{1-u}, \quad |u|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ you get
$$
1+2u+3u^2+...+nu^{n-1}=\frac{1-u^{n+1}}{(1-u)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)u^{n}}{1-u}, \quad |u|<1, \tag2
$$ and by making $n \to +\infty$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$, **using $|u|<1$**, gives 
$$
1+u+u^2+...+u^n+...=\frac{1}{1-u} \tag3
$$
$$
1+2u+3u^2+...+nu^{n-1}+...=\frac{1}{(1-u)^2} \tag4
$$

If you put $u=\dfrac{x}{10}$ in $(4)$, you obtain an answer to your question.

Comment: If you'd like, you can wait until $(3)$ to insist on $|u| < 1$.

Comment: @GFauxPas I see your point: $(1)$ and $(2)$ are valid just for $u \neq1$. Ok, next time :) Thanks!